# Why did moderator remove the valid answer?

Tags: discussion, moderation

Here is the question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36354711/difficult-to-run-the-svn-subversion. I can agree that the question is "bad", but the answer provided [helped the OP to solve the problem](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36354711/difficult-to-run-the-svn-subversion#comment60388481_36354711). So why to remove [helpful answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36356918/761095) that led the OP to the right solution?

Yes, this answer could be a comment to the original question, but it's too long to be readable in the format of a comment.

*It's a pity to see moderators acting more like automated bots rather than human beings. ;)*

> Don't read "various tutorials found on the Internet". Read the
>   [documentation before starting to configure the server](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.8/svn.serverconfig.html).
>
> You tell about /etc/httpd/conf.modules.d/10-subversion.conf which is a
>   config file for Apache HTTP Server but next you tell about `svnserve`
>   which is another built-in Subversion server. So it's totally unclear
>   what your intentions are. The question as it is now has to be closed
>   because it is "unsalvageable".

[image]

Comment: "unsalvageable" questions should not be answered. Someone with your reputation should know that.

Comment: The moderator *did* act like a human being - one that understands what constitutes an answer on Stack Overflow. Your "answer" was a comment. I've written hundreds of comments as detailed as yours. It's easy to do.

Comment: I removed it because apart from advice to "read the documentation here"... the only other content was basically commenting on what the OP had mentioned in their question - it's effectively a link only answer. To be useful in the future - it should contain information from the link to the OPs problem, but since you mention in your answer that you're not sure what exactly that is and that the question should be closed, it's unlikely that's practical.

Comment: @JonClements aww, it's becoming hard to help others on SO. Too many bad questions that should not get any answers at all. OK, will use comments next time.

Comment: @bahrep Bear in mind that it's possible that had you started with comments trying to get the OP to clarify what they really meant, there may well be an answerable question now. Failing that, if they didn't clarify, you'd know it wasn't worth your time to answer, voted to close (as you did), then move on to something worth your time and expertise.

Answer (score 31, accepted):

You shouldn't misuse the answer feature for saying that a question should be closed. When you think a question should be closed, you can vote to close it, and/or comment to that effect. Do not use an answer for this...

Without that part of your answer it's still link-only and low quality. Arguably maybe not worth the time it takes to delete it, but still a low quality answer.

You have 13.6k reputation, you should know this...